# Listview item click in Metro App?

Tags: javascript, html, microsoft-metro, winjs

Am using HTML5,WinJS for developing Metro application. Here am using my own service to display user details(nearly 5 fields) in Listview in my home-page. But each user contains more than 20 fields in service, So when I click on listview-item it has to navigate details-page and needs to show the details . I displayed listview with some details in home page , but am unable to perform clicking of item with more details . Hope my question is well.

Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

The WinJS.UI.ListView has an iteminvoked event that fires when you click or tap an item. More [info here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br211827.aspx).